# Developing API methods to return JSON

Tags: php

When developing API methods to return JSON with details I often find myself creating the following code:

```
    $response = array('success' => false);

    $user = User::getSessionUser();
    if($user->id > 0){
        if(ItemSKU::stringIsValid($sku)){

            $itemSKU = ItemSKU::getFromString($sku);
            if($itemSKU->isAvailable()){
                if(Carts::add($user->id, $sku)){
                    $response['success'] = true;
                }
                else{
                    $response['error'] = "Item was already added";
                }
            }
            else{
                $response['error'] = "Unavailable Item";
            }
        }
        else{
            $response['error'] = "Invalid SKU";
        }
    }
    else{
        $response['error'] = "Invalid User";
    }

    return response()->json($response);
```

How can I avoid using this nested `if`-`else` chain?

Comment: Your logic flow is easy to follow. No problems here.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I prefer avoiding such nested if-else constructs, simply by reversing the logic, e.g.:

```
if(!cond1)
    return value;
if(!cond2)
    return value2;
// etc.
```

instead of:

```
 if (cond1)
     if(!cond2)
         return value2;
 else
     return value;
```

Comment: Yeah, if you have tons of conditions a `return` statement is your friend, since it has the same net effect as the `if` block

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the error conditions first, and immediately return if they're true:

```
$response = array('success' => false);

$user = User::getSessionUser();
if(!($user->id > 0)){
    $response['error'] = "Invalid User";
    return response()->json($response);
}

if(!ItemSKU::stringIsValid($sku)){
    $response['error'] = "Invalid SKU";
    return response()->json($response);
}

$itemSKU = ItemSKU::getFromString($sku);

if(!$itemSKU->isAvailable()){
    $response['error'] = "Unavailable Item";
    return response()->json($response);
}

if(Carts::add($user->id, $sku)){
    $response['success'] = true;
}
else{
    $response['error'] = "Item was already added";
}  

return response()->json($response);
```